# mapping to enclose symbol under cursor with an expression that contains the symbol (revisited)

Tags: replace, macro

@saginaw answered a question I asked a long time ago, in [this thread](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/5982/mapping-to-enclose-symbol-under-cursor-with-an-expression-that-contains-the-symb/5985#5985).

Here's a code snippit of his suggestions that illustrates my problem:

```
function! s:PadMacro(type) abort
    if a:type ==# 'char'
        normal! `[v`]d
    elseif a:type ==# 'line'
        normal! '[V']d
    elseif a:type ==# 'v'
        normal! `<v`>d
    else
        return
    endif
    let string = '\Pad{' . @" . '}'
    silent execute "normal! i\<c-r>=string\r"
endfunction
nnoremap <silent> ;P :set operatorfunc=<sid>PadMacro<cr>g@
vnoremap <silent> ;P :<c-u>call <sid>PadMacro(visualmode())<cr>

a
aaa
```

Here are @saginaw's instructions

```
Instructions:
    If you put the previous code in your vimrc, it should do what you want.

    To use it, hit ;P{motion} and the PadMacro() function should enclose the characters covered by {motion} with \Pad{ and }.
```

The problem  I'm having is with the ;P{motion} command: If

(*) on the last line of the snippet I highlight the three aaa's by hitting v and the spacebar, then hit ;P

I get the following error

```
Error detected while processing function <SNR>7_PaddingFunction:
line   10:
E121: Undefined variable: g:enclosure
E15: Invalid expression: '\' . g:enclosure . '{' . @" . '}'
Press ENTER or type command to continu
```

HOWEVER, if I first modify the single a in the line above, by putting the cursor over it and then typing ;P (no 'v' then spacebar required), and AFTER DOING SO, repeat the command sequence on the line that begins with (*), the ;P command works as expected.

My ignorant guess is that something needs to be initialized in order for ;P, together with motion,  to work properly

Could somebody please advise how to get the (*) command sequence to work the first time?   Thanks for any advice.

At @Christian_Brabandt's request I'm posting the output of `:scriptnames`

```
1: ~/LOCALSVN/dotFiles/trunk/vimrc
  2: /usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/syntax.vim
  3: /usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/synload.vim
  4: /usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/syncolor.vim
  5: /usr/share/vim/vim74/filetype.vim
  6: ~/LOCALSVN/multiSystem/trunk/vimPlugins/unicode.vim/ftdetect/unicode.vim
  7: /usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/nosyntax.vim
  8: /usr/share/vim/vim74/colors/delek.vim
  9: ~/LOCALSVN/multiSystem/trunk/vimPlugins/unicode.vim/plugin/unicode.vim
 10: /usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/getscriptPlugin.vim
 11: /usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/gzip.vim
 12: /usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/logiPat.vim
 13: /usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/matchparen.vim
 14: /usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/netrwPlugin.vim
 15: /usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/rrhelper.vim
 16: /usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/spellfile.vim
 17: /usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/tarPlugin.vim
 18: /usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/tohtml.vim
 19: /usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/vimballPlugin.vim
 20: /usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/zipPlugin.vim
 21: /usr/share/vim/vim74/scripts.vim
```

My vimrc file is posted [here](https://are.berkeley.edu/~leo1730simon/personal/vimrc) and a text file that generates the problem is [here](https://are.berkeley.edu/~leo1730simon/personal/padProblem)

Comment: `E121: Undefined variable: g:enclosure` - this means you don't have a variable defined. However the code you have given in your question, does not even use this variable. I feel like we are missing something

Comment: This code is used by function `<SNR>7...`, so please show the output number 7 of `:scriptnames`

Comment: Output #7 is /usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/nosyntax.vim

Comment: Are you sure? `syntax/nosyntax.vim` does not contain any functions. You can also try `:verbose :fu <snr>7_PaddingFunction`. That one is responsible for your error and I suppose it has a bug.

Comment: Thanks, I posted the entire output of `:scriptnames`   I tried typing `:verbose :fu <snr>7_PaddingFunction` and received an error:  `E123: Undefined function: <SNR>7_PaddingFunction`

Comment: Please show that after the error above actually occurs. I don't think any of the vimplugins have a padding function and i know my unicode plugin does not. So I come to think, that are not all plugins that have been loaded when you see the error. So can you please reproduce the error and afterwards show the output of the commands I mentioned before?

Comment: I thought the best way to demonstrate to problem was to post my (very complicated)  .vimrc file and a sample that recreates the problem.     I've added links to them in my original post.    Thanks very much for your patience.

Answer (score 2):

This seems like a job for Tim Pope's [surround.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround).

Add the following to `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/tex.vim`:

```
let b:surround_{char2nr("P")} = "\\Pad{\r}"
```

Now you can do `ys{motion}P` or other surround operations (See `:h surround`). See `:h surround-customizing` for more information about customizing surround.vim.

There is also [vim-sandwich](https://github.com/machakann/vim-sandwich) which is an alternative to surround.vim.